# SPD Workflow trigger emails at specific time intervals

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Default Status is "Pending" as Drop down Menu:

- If requester submits a new form between 3:00 PM to 9:30 AM with Status as Pending Pause until 10:00 AM then send email to the person1 at 10:00 Am ,if person1 changed the status to Approved then the stop the email to the person1.
- If requester submits a new form between 10:00 AM to 12:00 PM with Status as Pending Pause until 12:30 PM then send email to assigned person1 at 12:30 ,if person1 changed the status to Approved then the stop the email to the person1
- If requester submits an new form between 12:30 PM to 2:30 PM with Status as Pending Pause until 3:00 PM then send email to assigned person1 at 3:00 PM ,if person1 changed the status to Approved then the stop the email to the person1

How to accomplish above task?

Please let me know,if anyone knows it.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Create a new Time Status column.

Use this calculate field as the new value in the calculated field

```
=([Created]-INT([Created]))*24
```

That gives you a number value you for the hours of the day (ie 10am is 10, 1:30pm is 13.5, etc).

In your workflow - create a three steps in a row where the workflow looks at the Time Status - and adjust accordingly.

Workflow Step #1 - 
If Time Status > 10 AND < 12
Wait till 12:30 then Check the Approval status = Approved, if not approved Send email

Workflow Step #2 -
If Time Status > 12.5 AND < 14.5
Wait till 3pm then Send email

Workflow Step#3 -
Wait till 10am on the next day ([Created] + 1), Check Approval Status = Approved, if not send email.

Comment: Hi McClain,   I am not able check the Condition with Time Status because Time Status value type as Double,Double not accepting to check with conditions >,< in SPD and which action do i need to take for  (created+1).

Comment: @Pradeep Are you trying to write this in SP Designer? Created should be the default Created field in every SP List. When you create a new column in any SP List, using a "Calculated field" should be one of the default choices. Placing that code as the "Calculation" in your calulated field should solve that for you. Giving you a integer anyway to work with. Then in SP Designer, you should be able to start that new list workflow using the three steps I laid out. Which SP Version are you using? 2007? 10? 13? I just tried it in both 07/10 and it worked without issue.

Comment: @Hi Josh McClain,I have added the Time Status Column to the SP List as Calculated with Formaulae as above,but if I am selecting current Item as "Time Status" as column in Condition "if any value equals value".I am not getting the greater than,lesser than conditions.please tell me,how can i get that